# Can I use the same frame layout (as container) to display DrawerLayout and RecyclerView?

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview, drawerlayout

I have a navigation drawer that using `RecyclerView` layout. In the same time, my main page use `RecyclerView` layout too. How to manage it optimally?

This is my **activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!--Toolbar-->
<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_good" />

<!--Mulai layout drawer-->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true">
        </FrameLayout>

    <!--Fragment Drawer-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
        android:name="com.mundane.hortipedia.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I just want to fetch my data from sqlite database and show them to R.id.my_recycler_view. But it doesn't work.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6y9wxk << my layout schema

Comment: i think the android guidelines says that drawerlayout must be your xml's root container.
see this https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: Ok got it. so it's permitted to put Recyclerview (my_recycler_view) inside FrameLayout (container), or i have to create new fragment for my_recycler_view then replace the container. which is better?

Comment: Sorry if it's bothering, i'm very newbie in Android programming,  furthermore i am not a native English speaker so it's took longer time to understand its concepts.

Comment: yes, you can put whatever you want in your drawerlayout, even a kitty ;D

Updating my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this as main layout, as per android guidelines drawerlayout must be root container as the first child container of drawerlayout is main page and second child is drawer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_main_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_action_good" />

        <!--Toolbar-->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <!--Framelayout Drawer-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="give the desired width here"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I hope this will help

Comment: Code only anwers are discouraged in SO.

Comment: <!--RecyclerView Drawer--> cover up other elements. When i replaced it with my fragment elament, **app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />**  doesnt work properly. i have a recyclerview which called by fragment element.

Comment: Sorry for going too straight while answering. i will update my answer

Comment: Can not resolve symbol > R. in MainActivity. Should I add v4 library in my gradle?

Comment: which symbol? ">", this?

Comment: yes u should add 

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
in build gradle